# Какая разница между двумя запусками окна?

Tags: qt, c++

**Первый способ**:

```
MyWindow *wnd = new MyWindow(this);  
wnd->show();
```

**Второй способ**:

```
MyWindow wnd(this);  
wnd.show();  
wnd.exec();
```

Зачем во втором способе нужен `exec()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разница между `show()` и `exec()` состоит в том, что при `show()` основной поток продолжает выполняться, а при `exec()` выполнение основной программы приостанавливается до закрытия child-окна. Применяется, например, в модальных диалогах.

Видимо, в коде, из которого вы взяли второй пример, дочернее окно делает что-то, что необходимо основному. Поэтому основной поток ждет закрытия дочернего окна.